# on which os should i try the vs2010 beta1? which emulator is faster?

Tags: windows, visual-studio, virtualization

I just downloaded the VS 2010 Beta1 Pro and I want to setup a vm to try the new devenv.
Which os and which emulator software should I try for the best performaces? (currently I've XP sp3, Win 7 RC, Win 2008).

Comment: Xp SP3 (still working with c++ on vs2003)

Answer (score 0):

hmm....Win 7 or 2008. Though I'd say Win 7 as that better reflects Microsoft's latest dev environment....you wouldn't really do dev on 2008....though you could.

Personally I'd dual boot, especially as Win 7 RC is free, and run it natively.

Otherwise I'd definitely make sure you can virtualize with full hardware acceleration.

[this bit of software by gibson](http://www.grc.com/securable.htm) will help you identify whether your hardware supports full hardware accelaration.

If it does, obviously you'll need a VM solution which can make use of that, such as VMWare or MS HyperV